# No such property: developmentModeActive for class issue when run schema-export

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-3.0

Environment:

- Grails Version: 3.0.3
- Groovy Version: 2.4.3
- JVM Version: 1.8.0_45

Steps:

1. create app by create-app
2. add classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate:4.3.8.1" to build.gradle
3. run command grails schema-export

The result is failed, the key error log:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-11" groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: developmentModeActive for class: grails.ui.command.GrailsApplicationContextCommandRunner
```

Stacktrace:

> Possible solutions: developmentModeActive at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:51)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:304)
>       at grails.boot.GrailsApp$_enableDevelopmentModeWatch_closure1.doCall(GrailsApp.groovy:161)
>       at grails.boot.GrailsApp$_enableDevelopmentModeWatch_closure1.doCall(GrailsApp.groovy)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:292)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
>       at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
>       at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:417)
>       at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:504)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Command execution error: Cannot invoke method mkdirs() on null object :schemaExport FAILED

Is this a bug for grails 3 ? or I make something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been fixed in **grails 3.0.4**.

But you still have to apply the hibernate dependency fix. I'll describe it here to make the answer more helpful to others (based on [this bug-report](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/659)):

Add a hibernate dependency to `buildscript.dependencies` section of your `build.gradle` so it looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.1.1'

        // add this line
        classpath 'org.grails.plugins:hibernate:4.3.10.4'
    }
}
```