# error while exporting grails 2 plugin to grails 3

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin, grails-3.0, grails-3.0.9

I have been trying to upgrade the grails spring-security-ui plugin to grails 3. As mentioned in the docs I have copied all the dependencies to build.gradle.

The file looks something like this.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
    }
}

plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "0.5.2.RELEASE"
    id "com.jfrog.bintray" version "1.2"
}

version "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
group "org.grails.plugins"

apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: "spring-boot"
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-plugin"
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-gsp"
// Used for publishing to central repository, remove if not needed
apply from:'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grails/grails-profile-repository/master/profiles/plugin/templates/grailsCentralPublishing.gradle'
apply from:'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grails/grails-profile-repository/master/profiles/plugin/templates/bintrayPublishing.gradle'

ext {
    grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    gradleWrapperVersion = project.gradleWrapperVersion
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
    mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false
}

dependencies {
    provided 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging'
    provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"

    provided "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    provided "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    provided 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'

    compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC3'
    compile ':mail:1.0.5'
    compile ':jquery:1.11.1'
    compile ':jquery-ui:1.10.3'
    compile ':famfamfam:1.0.1'

    compile ':spring-security-acl:2.0-RC1', {
        export = false
    }

    compile ":hibernate:3.6.10.14", {
        export = false
    }

    build ':release:3.0.1', ':rest-client-builder:2.0.1', {
        export = false
    }

    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"

    console "org.grails:grails-console"
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = gradleWrapperVersion
}
```

When I try to install the plugin I get an error like this

```
| Error Error initializing classpath: No such property: export for class: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultExternalModuleDependency_Decorated (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: export for class: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultExternalModuleDependency_Decorated
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ExtraPropertiesDynamicObjectAdapter.setProperty(ExtraPropertiesDynamicObjectAdapter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.setProperty(CompositeDynamicObject.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultExternalModuleDependency_Decorated.setProperty(Unknown Source)
    at build_3l359y3diorgc61r1z5bdizfw$_run_closure4_closure8.doCall(/mnt/data/Work/Tutorials/Practice/grails/grails-spring-security-ui-master/build.gradle:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:67)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.create(DefaultDependencyHandler.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.doAdd(DefaultDependencyHandler.java:83)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.methodMissing(DefaultDependencyHandler.java:117)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:225)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:163)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at build_3l359y3diorgc61r1z5bdizfw$_run_closure4.doCall(/mnt/data/Work/Tutorials/Practice/grails/grails-spring-security-ui-master/build.gradle:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:67)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.dependencies(AbstractProject.java:831)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:225)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:147)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.methodMissing(BasicScript.java:79)
    at build_3l359y3diorgc61r1z5bdizfw.run(/mnt/data/Work/Tutorials/Practice/grails/grails-spring-security-ui-master/build.gradle:53)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:154)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:492)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:86)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getBuildAnalysis(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:97)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.configure(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:84)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ClientProvidedBuildAction.run(ClientProvidedBuildAction.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ClientProvidedBuildAction.run(ClientProvidedBuildAction.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
| Error Error initializing classpath: No such property: export for class: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultExternalModuleDependency_Decorated
```

I have gone through the documentation for writing plugins. export is very much a valid entry. Why am I getting such an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1:**
Use `provided` rather than `compile 'something', { export = false}` as:

```
configurations {
    provided
}
sourceSets {
    main { 
          compileClasspath += configurations.provided 
    }
}
dependencies {
    provided ':spring-security-acl:2.0-RC1'
}
```

Note: I didn't test this but it should work.

**Solution 2:**

Related issues have been solved/fixed in grails 3.0.4. Try exporting it to 3.0.4 version.

Example:

1. [No such property: developmentModeActive for class issue when run schema-export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31604839/no-such-property-developmentmodeactive-for-class-issue-when-run-schema-export)
2. https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9099